# semifinite measure $\mu$ property

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\mu$-semifinite measure in space $(X,\mathcal{A})$ and $A\in \mathcal{A}$ with $\mu(\mathcal{A})=\infty \Rightarrow \forall  M\in \mathbb{R}^+, \exists B\in\mathcal{A}$ so that $B\subset A \ , \ M<\mu(B)<\infty$

I encountered this problem today and I also found a proof in some old handscript which confused me.

It fist denotes $S := \{B\in\mathcal{A}: B\subseteq A, 0<\mu(B)<\infty\}$ and $s = sup(S)$

$S$ is non-empty since $\mu$-semifinite measure $\Rightarrow$ $s>0$ and that's how it starts

my question is this: $sup(S)$ is supposed to be a set as a union of sets since $S$ is denoted as a family of sets (the definition of the supremum of a set family implies it), so is this $s>0$ has any meaning at all? Am I missing something here?

Comment: The set you need to consider is $S := \{\mu(B): B\in\mathcal{A}, B\subseteq A, 0<\mu(B)<\infty\}$. Then $S$ is not empty. And you must prove that $\sup(S)=+\infty$.

Comment: @Ramiro I thought so, it was a typographic mistake after all. Thank you, I can take it from here.